# C: assign 2d array of struct

Tags: c, arrays

#### Background

I have a struct with two 2D arrays...

```
typedef struct v
{
    int *b;
    int *a;
} v;
```

Inside my main function I have...

```
int A [M][K] = {{2,2},{2,2}, {3,2} };
int B [K][N] = {{2,2,2},{2,2,2}};
struct v *data= (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));
data.a->A;
data.b->B;
pthread_create(&multiplicationWorker, NULL, (void *) &alterAarrays,  data);
```

...and a private function...

```
void alterArrays ( v* coords)
{
    ...
}
```

---

#### Question:

I want to pass references to the 2D arrays inside `alterArrays`.  Also it won't let me assign the values of the 2D arrays like this.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `data.a->A;` That isn't valid and wouldn't do anything useful even if it were

Answer (score 2):

Define sizes:

```
#define K 2
#define M 3
#define N 3
```

---

If you want to use arrays in your struct:

Define struct (did you mean to call these `a` and `b`? You refer to them as this in the code. Also, the dimensions originally differed from the arrays in the code:

```
typedef struct v
{
    int a [M][K];
    int b [K][N];
} v;
```

Then the copies:

```
int A [M][K] = {{2,2},{2,2}, {3,2} };
int B [K][N] = {{2,2,2},{2,2,2}};
struct v *data= (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));

memcpy(data->a, A, M * K * sizeof(int));
memcpy(data->b, B, K * N * sizeof(int));
```

---

If you want to use pointers in your struct:

Define struct:

```
typedef struct v
{
    int (*a)[K];
    int (*b)[N];
} v;
```

And you need to make `A` and `B` global, so they are not on the stack. So define them at the top of your source file:

```
int A [M][K] = {{2,2},{2,2}, {3,2} };
int B [K][N] = {{2,2,2},{2,2,2}};
```

Then the assignment:

```
struct v *data= (struct v *) malloc(sizeof(struct v));

data->a = A;
data->b = B;
```

Comment: Will this change the values of A and B? because that is what I want.  Seems to me like a copy would not do so

Comment: No. If you want to change `A` and `B`, then you need to use pointers in the struct, rather than arrays. Also, you should either make `A` and `B` global, or put them on the heap.